# Installing emerald on ubuntu 16.10

Tags: compiz, 16.10, emerald

hey guys how can I install emerald for compiz in ubuntu 16.10?

Comment: I haven't used it but, this might be helpful to you: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2321453

Comment: thanks for that, but I already tried it. didnt work for some reason

Comment: Please state what you tried so helpers don't waste time offering the same solutions (already tried).

Comment: It looks like [this project](https://code.launchpad.net/emerald) died in 2011.  You might be interested in the [PPA search](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+ppas?name_filter=emerald) But I doubt you will find a package for Yaketty (16.10)

Answer (score 1):

I downloaded and installed debian packages for my arch (amd64) from here:

https://launchpad.net/~nilarimogard/+archive/ubuntu/webupd8/+sourcepub/4063001/+listing-archive-extra

and it worked!

After that, I exported my favourite emerald theme from my Slackware, but you may need to download some existing theme/collection, or create one by your own, because the theme manager is empty with only emerald.